# Server 2008 R2 Disk Management Green Outline Extend C Drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, disk-space-utilization, diskmanagement, partition

In the Server 2008 R2 disk management snap-in I have Disk 0 which has these partitions:

1. boot partition - 71mb
2. a Recovery partition 3gb
3. OS (C:) 40gb
4. DATAPART1 (D:) 150gb
5. Free space 40gb

Disk 0 is a basic disk (instead of a dynamic disk).

So I would like to extend C: however when I right click on it I do not have the option to extend it is greyed out.  The 40gb of free space was freed from DATAPART1, the two are bound by a dark green box which seems to signify that they are "together".

I am assuming that I cannot extend C: because it appears to the system as there is no excess free space because it is still being reserved by DATAPART1.

What is the green box around DATAPART1 and the free space, and how can I make changes to allow C: to extend?

Comment: Aha... I just noticed the legend on the bottom, duh ;)  The dark green box means "Extended partition".  C of course is a logical drive.  So I guess my question is how do I add the free space that is in the extended partition to C which is a logical drive?

Answer (score 1):

The partition modification tools that are built into Windows are inadequate for most real-world scenarios. Run a full backup and then boot into something like PartedMagic. If the changes that you are making require any data blocks to be relocated, be prepared for them to take a very long time.